# Write a program to scroll text using java swing

Tags: java, swing, animation

There are two java files Animate and Anim1.The Anim1 file has the JFrame and I want to attach the Animate file which has the logic of text scrolling by the screen(supposed to be the JFrame screen).But I cannot find a way.And also the code is throwing the following compile time error-
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method repaint() is undefined for the type Animation

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Animation implements Runnable {
    int x=500;
    String s="hello world";
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            repaint();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("hello world", x,-10 );
        x--;
        if(x< -100){
            x=500;
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Anim1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Animation a= new Animation();
        Thread t= new Thread(a);
        t.start();

        JFrame frame= new JFrame("animate");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }
}
```

Comment: `"The method repaint() is undefined for the type Animation"` - Well, you're invoking a method called `repaint()`, where do you define that method?

Comment: You want to invoke `repaint()` on the JFrame.

Comment: no..isnt the the repaint() method call the paint(graphics g) method....isn't is automated

Comment: But the crux of the question is how to add that scrolling text logic in animate file to the anim1 file which has the jframe

Comment: @David: isnt the repaint() method is automated to call the paint(Graphics g)

Comment: @gramsci_11: not if your class does not extend a Swing component.

Answer (score 5):

The repaint method is found in Swing components -- same for the paint and paintComponent. Calling it inside of a class that does not extend a Swing comopnent does not make sense unless you're making the repaint call on another object that is a component. Likewise giving a non-component class a paint method makes no sense since you're not overriding any painting method.

Likely your Animation class should **extend JPanel** so that it can override paintComponent (**not** paint) and so that the `repaint()` call makes sense. Also **always** pre-pend your painting method (or any other method that you *think* overrides a parent method) with the `@Override` annotation. This way the compiler will complain to you when you're not overriding the method correctly (or at all).  You'll also want to call the super's painting method inside of your override.

Most important: read the Swing painting tutorials as it's all explained there. Check out: [Performing custom painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Your painting method would look something like so:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // always call the super's method to clean "dirty" pixels
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // then draw the String. Make y a field too, so it can be controlled
    // more easily
    g.drawString(s, x, y);
}
```

Note that I don't change the x value or call any state-changing code within my painting method, and that's by design. The paintComponent method is for painting **only**. You don't have full control over whether or even if it will be called, and it can be called **multiple** times.

Instead the x value should be changed within the "game loop", here your Runnable's `run()` method. Also, as per my comments, while this code can be created using Thread/Runnable, it's *safer* to instead use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to drive the animation instead, since this saves you from having to worry so much about Swing threading issues.

Comment: I have used import.javax.swing* statement and the compilation error for repaint() is gone....but the I didn't get the thing you said about extending JPanel and the paintComponent() stuff...and finally there are no compilation errors but the text is not scrolling over the frame

Comment: @gramsci_11: regarding your first comment -- do you have any code that **adds** your component to the JFrame?

Comment: @ Hovercraft: no..i have no code. I am stuck on that part..how to add the components to the JFrame..I tried to add the thread with frame.add(t), but that was incorrect..

Comment: @gramsci_11: you're doing a lot of guessing, something that might work with simple console applications, but won't work when learning a new and complex library, such as the Swing GUI. To avoid doing that, again do use the tutorials. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info). As for what you add -- you add your component itself to the JFrame, not the thread. Also, drawing something at y position -10 makes no sense either. Please do check these important tutorials.

Comment: @gramsci_11: also, to keep things simple if this were my application, I'd use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to drive my application and not a Thread/Runnable. It's just a lot safer that way -- although it can be done with Thread/Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps .repaint() needs to be passed something to work. Often animations will take place on a canvas then you would update that. The update method would have to be made separate with all of the things you wish to update.

```
canvas.update()
public void update(){
what it is you wish to update
canvas.draw()
}
```

I hope this helps. EDIT so your canvas is your JFrame

Comment: but how to add the animate file to the Jframe or even canvas

Comment: saying "isn't my question clear" (paraphrasing the grammar) isn't going to help. If this is not what you were asking please rephrase. As for your first comment, you could override the animate class with your own which is what many people do.

Comment: could you provide me with any external links to understand this thing properly...

Comment: well I first learned this concept in Python, then again recently in java through Android so here is the video I watched (you can just keep skipping through the video and look at all the code he posted throughout the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPzTSpZwFoU&t=10s